# Unity - Erro: Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Instantiate "Spawn" necessito de ajuda

Tags: unity3d, unity-5, game

Este é o meu primeiro jogo e ele roda na unity porém justo quando uso o botão de atirar de este erro "Unity - Erro: Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Instantiate". segue o codigo 
abaixo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {
    private SpriteRenderer mySpriteRenderer;
    public int damage = 40;
    public GameObject bullet;
    private Transform SpawnerB;
    public float fireRate = 0.3f;
    public float nextFire = 0.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {
        mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        bullet = GameObject.FindWithTag ("bull");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward, mousePos - transform.position);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire) {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate (bullet, SpawnerB.position, transform.rotation, );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha amigo, me parece que a sua Unity não está encontrando seu objeto no Start, confere se estão com a Tag (cuidado para não confundir a Tag com a Layer), e mexo com a Unity a 3 anos, e deixo a dica, mesmo estando no Start(), se o objeto já está em cena, é melhor setá-lo na mão é muito mais leve que você dar um FindWithTag isso acaba sendo pesado. Outra dica é evitar variáveis publicas, caso você apenas queira ver elas no Inspector. tem como colocar elas assim:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {
    SpriteRenderer mySpriteRenderer;
    [SerializeField]
    int damage = 40;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject bullet;
    Transform SpawnerB;
    [SerializeField]
    float fireRate = 0.3f;
    [SerializeField]
    float nextFire = 0.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {
        mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        bullet = GameObject.FindWithTag ("bull");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward, mousePos - transform.position);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire) {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate (bullet, SpawnerB.position, transform.rotation, );
        }
    }

}
```

As variáveis privadas não possuem a necessidade de colocar o `private` na sua frente, pois por padrão as variáveis são privadas.